# How to position a geom_text beneath each group's name in the margin of a ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a geom_text for each group that shows the sample size for that group. I want to position that geom in the margin so that it doesn't occlude any data, ideally directly below the group name.

For example:

```
mt = mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(N = n())

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = hp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = mt, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = 0, label = paste("N = ", N)))
```

[Resulting graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdwJW.png)

How do I position the geoms underneath the group names (here, the number of cyl)?
Also, I would much prefer a method that doesn't nudge the geom with reference to the scale on the graph, because I want this code to apply for many different graphs with different scales on the Y-axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `geom_text` create a column by concatanating the category aka `cyl` and the counts and map this variable on `x`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)

mt <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(x = paste0(cyl, "\nN = ", n()))

ggplot(mt, aes(x = x, y = hp, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]